# Wordpress local EC2 directory redirect to S3

Tags: wordpress, bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm moving a site from hosted to AWS. I've installed WP on a new ec2 instance, and have the entire (old) site backed up in s3. It is possible to redirect directories on my ec2 instance to s3? For example if WP asks for an file in the local /images folder or (even better) /var/www, could I somehow redirect the inquiry for that file to the relevant file in s3? Clearly, I don't want to store the bulk of the site on EC2 EBS as it's ~45GB & S3 is cheaper.

If there's an altogether better way I'm open to that too.

Comment: Amazon EBS Throughput Optimized HDD (st1) volumes are $0.045 per GB-month, S3 is $0.0245 per GB. You are trying to save less than 1$ per month?

Comment: The purpose of the site is archival and I planned to use S3 IA, but you have a point.

Comment: There sure are use cases for S3, but with 45GB of data it is certainly not cost saving :)

Answer (score 0):

```
1. Create AWS account and create ec2 instance for same as follows:
-> select Linux AMI
->t2.micro
->security groups must be http,secure group and custom tcp (3306 for mysql)
->key generate(.pem file)
-> launch instances

2. on windows create .ppk file from pem using puttygen

3. login to your instance using putty
host - ec2-user@xxxxxxxxxxxxx
user - ec2-user
ssh(auth)-ppk file

connection ---> Success

4. after successful login perform these commands

>[ec2-user ~]$ sudo yum update -y
>sudo yum install -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
>sudo service httpd start
>sudo chkconfig httpd on
>chkconfig --list httpd
>ls -l /var/www
> sudo usermod -a -G apache ec2-user
>sudo chown -R ec2-user:apache /var/www
>echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
>http://my.public.dns.amazonaws.com/phpinfo.php
>sudo yum list installed httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd
>rm /var/www/html/phpinfo.php
>sudo service mysqld start
>sudo mysql_secure_installation
>sudo service mysqld stop
>sudo chkconfig mysqld on
>sudo yum install php70-mbstring.x86_64 php70-zip.x86_64 -y
>cd /var/www/html
>wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz
>tar -xvzf phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.tar.gz
>http://my.public.dns.amazonaws.com/phpMyAdmin
>chkconfig --list httpd
>sudo yum remove -y httpd24 php70 mysql56-server php70-mysqlnd perl-DBD-MySQL56
>sudo yum install -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd
>sudo yum remove -y httpd24 php56 mysql55-server php56-mysqlnd perl-DBD-MySQL55
>from localhost go to settings->site settings -> change site and home url
>export db(sql.zip)
>login to phpmyadmin
>import sql.zip here
>from your project folder upload your code to git or bitbucket
>now move to var/www/html
>sudo git pull origin master
> edit wp-config.php with your favorite text editor
(sudo nano wp-config.php)
>set values for db,db_name,db_host,db_user
(db host should be ip for your instance)
```

Comment: Please don't post the exact same answer to multiple questions.  If they can be answered with the same answer one should closed as a duplicate of the other.